# set two different types of in text citation?

Tags: biblatex, graphics, styles

Is it possible to set two different types of citations in the same document?
specifically, i'd like to have a superscript number with page (if possible, the page in comment-style), and a full author+title+year (to be used in image captions).

example of the first style:

[image: first style]

example of the second style:

[image]

both cases are also links to the references.
i'm using biblatex. but I coundn't discover how to set styles individually (and how to add comments in the final pdf, for the first style). any light in the right direction is apreciated.
thanks in advance!